# pandas: how to merge multiple indexes together?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two levels of index, and I want to merge them into one level of index. I looked at methods such as reset_index and reindex, but they don't seem to be what I need. Another way I can think of is adding a new column containing the merged indexes, set that column as the new index using pivot_table, and delete the old indexes. But I'm wondering is there a more elegant way to do this. Any input is welcomed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Useful if you post raw input data, code and desired output

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```
df.index = df.index.values
```

will give you tuples in a single level if that's what you mean by 'merge'.